# CSS: How to prevent scrolling on iOS Safari?

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog, mobile-safari

I created a modal. When the modal is open I'm stopping the scroll on Desktop with `overflow:hidden;` to the `<body>`. It's working.

But it's not working on my iPhone 6s Mobile Safari.

How can I prevent scrolling when the modal is open in mobile safari?

Comment: Presented answer was no longer working on iOS 11, 12

Answer (score 40):

Combine it with `position: fixed` to do this on iOS…

```
overflow: hidden;
position: fixed;
```

Comment: Sorry to resurrect an old thread, but this answer works only if the modal is being triggered while the page is scrolled all the way to the top. If the page is scrolled down at all then setting "position: fixed" will scroll you back to the top before triggering the modal instead of leaving you where you were when you triggered the modal. Is there a solution that addresses this as well?

Comment: @0sin Set the body's `height` to its `scrollHeight`, then make the children `fixed` and use `transform: 'translateY(-' + body.scrollTop + 'px)'` on them

Comment: @aleclarson not hacky at all, gotta love iOS

Comment: Thanks - that sorted it for me! When will the trillion dollar company finally pull their finger out and sort out all these crappy IOS bugs? I'm fed up having to do hacks around issues that shouldn't even be issues *hmmmf*

Comment: Just to say that the "position: fixed" would cause black box on the bottom of the website on iPhoneX, and probably any build later than that.

Answer (score 30):

There isn't (to my knowledge) a great way to accomplish this with CSS without repercussions on the UX.

While it's Javascript, and not CSS, the best way I've found to do this is the following:

```
// Disable scrolling.
document.ontouchmove = function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}

// Enable scrolling.
document.ontouchmove = function (e) {
  return true;
}
```

Comment: If you are using this for modals, chances are you are using javascript anyway... so this works great. This is the best solution I have found, as setting position: fixed resets the scroll position on the page. If you just pair this with overflow: hidden, it works for both desktop and mobile and does not effect scroll position

Comment: This plus `overflow: hidden` is the only thing I've been able to get to work

Comment: Tested on Iphone 7. This is not working.

Comment: one issue with this solution, is when you are using this with scrollable modals, it disable the scroll inside the modal

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks!

Comment: Tested on iPhoneX, not working. Neither do `window.ontouchmove`.